# Reused object will not call `__destruct`?

Tags: php, destructor

I was trying to make a "pool" like structure in a CLI program, which includes lots of "borrowing" and "recycling". And while testing things, I encountered something quite unexpected:

```
<?php
class FOO
{
    public static $pool=[];
    public static function get()
    {
        if(empty(self::$pool))
        {
            self::$pool[]=new self(mt_rand(1000,9999));
        }
        return array_shift(self::$pool);
    }
    protected static function recycle(FOO $foo)
    {
        echo "Recycling {$foo->num}\n";
        self::$pool[]=$foo;
    }

    public $num;
    protected function __construct(int $num)
    {
        $this->num=$num;
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        static::recycle($this);
    }
}
function Bar()
{
    $foo=FOO::get();
    echo "Got {$foo->num}\n";
}
echo "Bar\n";
Bar();
echo "Bar\n";
Bar();
echo "Bar\n";
Bar();
echo "Bar\n";
Bar();
print_r(FOO::$pool);
echo "End.\n";
```

The output is:

```
Bar
Got 2911
Recycling 2911
Bar
Got 2911
Bar
Got 1038
Recycling 1038
Bar
Got 1038
Array
(
)
End.
```

If I limit the `Bar()` call to 3 times instead of 4, I got the following output:

```
Bar
Got 7278
Recycling 7278
Bar
Got 7278
Bar
Got 6703
Recycling 6703
Array
(
    [0] => FOO Object
        (
            [num] => 6703
        )

)
End.
```

Here you can see, when an object is "reused" (see 2911 and 1038 in example 1, 7278 in example 2), its `__destruct()` will not be called; instead, it will simply disappear.

I'm confused. Why would this happen? Why wouldn't `FOO->__destruct` got called every time? And is it possible to make instances of `FOO` auto recycle itself?

I'm testing this in PHP-7.2, behavior observed both in Windows and WSL-Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know destructors will not be called twice for the same object. It is generally a bad practice to reuse objects from the destructor. An object whose destructor was called should be destroyed, not reused. In your test script it doesn't cause any serious issues, but in real life, such usage could lead to unexpected behaviours if the developer is not careful.

At first when I read your question, I was worried that you have created a memory leak, but that is not the case. The destructor is called as soon as you leave the scope of `Bar()` only if it hasn't been called yet on this object. However, because you save the reference and increase the `ref_count` of this object inside of the `__destruct()` the garbage collector cannot collect the object yet. It must wait until the next time when you decrease the `ref_count` of this object.

The process can be explained as follows (simplified):

1. You call `Bar()` function which creates an instance of `FOO`. An object is created and assigned to `$foo`. (`ref_count = 1`)
2. Upon the end of `Bar()` the only reference to this object is lost (`ref_count = 0`), which means PHP starts the process of destroying the object.
   2.1. The destructor is called. Inside of the destructor you increase the `ref_count` to 1.
   2.2. The next step would be for the GC to collect the object, but the `ref_count` is not zero. This could mean a cycle or like in your example, a new reference has been created in the destructor. GC must wait until there are no uncyclical references to collect the object.
3. You call `Bar()` again. You shift the same object from static array, which means that the reference inside of `FOO::$pool` is gone, but you immediately assign it to `$foo`. (`ref_count = 1`)
4. Upon the end of `Bar()` the only reference to this object is lost (`ref_count = 0`), which means GC can finally collect this object. The destructor has already been called, so there is no other action to be taken here.

You didn't recycle the object, you merely prolonged its existance in the memory. You could access it for a little longer, but for PHP that object was already in the process of being destroyed.

Comment: Was about to post something similar, but this is a lot better thought-out. Excellent answer. Just to be sure; if `Bar()` is called an odd number of time, the GC will collect the last instance only when the script finishes, right? Since there will remain a ref_count of 1 from that static property then.

Comment: That is correct. At the end of the script's execution the static array inside of `FOO` will be destroyed and the objects which were referenced within will also be collected. This is however a moot point, since all memory will be freed when the script ends.

Comment: Right, not a problem in itself, just wanted to make sure I got that part right. Thanks.

Comment: OK cool, something I have thought of but never "want"ed to confirm. I guess I should stick to manual recycle. Thanks!